# TFS express with google drive

Tags: tfs, google-drive-api, repository

Can I combine tfs express server with google drive for windows to get my free repository in the cloud?
Anyone knows other alternative with this two things?  It has to be free.

Answer (score 1):

TFS Express uses SQL Express as repository. Don't see how you can use it with google drive, but you can try [Team Foundation Service](http://tfspreview.com). It's free for now, because it's still in preview.

What will happen after preview I really don't. I just hope they will have some free package.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use TFS Express with a cloud storage option to suddenly get a cloud version of TFS. But, in the past few years Microsoft hasn't sat still, so now you can get a cloud-hosted version of TFS by creating a [Visual Studio Team Services account](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/).

This service is also free for up to 5 users, plus you'll get a lot of things that didn't come with TFS Express.